# How to set the default font size of a new Stickie?

Tags: macos, font, stickies

When I create a new sticky the font is horribly small, any ideas on how to change the font please?

Comment: `CMD` + `+` works.

Comment: that changes the currently used font but it doesn't change the default font

Answer (score 15):

Change the font size of a selected Sticky note (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>), then go to *Window → Use as Default*

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't save the font :-(  It saves some other settings but importantly not the font size...the default is so so so tiny!

Comment: @atreeon It certainly does save the font and the size here, in both Sierra (where it's under "Note > Use as default") and Catalina.  What OS are you on?  Also consider that you may have another underlying problem.

Comment: @atreeon Also to consider is the way you add text to the sticky, i.e. is it typed, imported, copied and pasted, or copied & pasted with matching style...

Comment: I select: cmd + T -> select font -> window -> use as default but it doesn't work.  I've tried typing, copying but it doesn't change the default font when I open up a new sticky.  I'm on Catalina.

Comment: It does save the 'float on top' setting and the colour; so something is working but none of the font options change from the default when I open a new sticky

Comment: All I can think of is either the preference file (plist), but I hadn't noticed many, if any plist corruptions for quite some time now, or some kind of font issue.

Comment: I got this solution to work on macOS Big Sur version 11.6 by: creating a new note, typing in (not copying) text, setting the font and font size, then setting Window → Use as Default.  Every subsequent new note consistently uses the the newly set font and font size settings.