# How to set default styles for Notes app

Tags: macos, notes.app

In the MacOS Notes app, I would like to set my own default font colors for different markup styles (headings, mono, title, etc).

For example, when creating a new note all the headings would be green and the title would be red.

I'm aware of the advice [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302763/how-can-i-change-default-font-notes-sierra-high-sierra) about changing the `.strings` file but it looks like that is now outdated.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Are you asking for alternative (but probably non-existent) way of modifying Notes' behaviour?  Or are you asking for an alternative app (e.g. MS Word) which would do what you want?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify the Notes app.

Comment: So, I'm here because I need to *remember* how I did it. I changed the default font face for monospacing to Courier New on one Mac but now on a new Mac (not restored from a back up of an older Mac), I want to do the same, but can't find a place to do it. I remember something about "set as default"; which may not exist in newer OS versions. Maybe, because I changed it before it went away, the plist, or whatever controls this, was already changed before the option did ... theoretically.