# Configure Native Notes.app to Use Monospaced by Default

Tags: font, notes.app, defaults

For every carriage return on a monospaced line, the following line resets to the default Body format. I used [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302763/how-can-i-change-default-font-notes-sierra-high-sierra) post as a reference but everything's outdated and I don't find anything  else recent out there. What are your suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It’s currently not possible to set new notes to default to monospaced.

I’m not able to reproduce your issue though; if I choose monospaced from the format dropdown then return will keep the monospaced formatting until I manually choose Body formatting again. Check your OS is up to date (I’m on Big Sur 11.3 and iOS 14.5 and don’t have a non-beta install to test).